# Python parsing for MySQL import

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.3

My first python project is a converter to get data in shape for MySQL import. 
I've already cut away all unwanted lines of the file using `target.writelines(data[start:stop])`.

Now I've got about 2000 Lines like this:

1,2011,54,0,.375,-.183,2.325,1.221,0,.016,0,0,431.4,.345,1.563,25.13,13.23

whereas 54 represents the julian day.

For import to a table with 3 rows (datetime, value id, value) it should be turned into:

2011-23-02 00:00:00,1,-0.183
2011-23-02 00:00:00,2,2.325
2011-23-02 00:00:00,3,1.221
2011-23-02 00:00:00,4,0
2011-23-02 00:00:00,5,0.016
2011-23-02 00:00:00,6,0
2011-23-02 00:00:00,7,0
2011-23-02 00:00:00,8,431.4
2011-23-02 00:00:00,9,0.345
2011-23-02 00:00:00,10,1.563

Note the first, fifth and the two last values have been removed. First and fifth are present in every line, the two last ones only at 0 and 12 o'clock.

I've read that the conversion from julian can be archived with the datetime module ([Convert julian day into date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17216169/convert-julian-day-into-date)).

Which Python tools would you suggest to get the job done efficiently?

UPDATE

Thank you CoDEmanX, I implemented your suggested code with some alternations and am almost done. 2 Questions are left:

1. Is there a built in way to handle leap years correctly (e.g. julian 60 should be 29th Feb in a leap year and 1st Mar the other years)?
2. I tried to implement the time (hours, minutes). Since the time var varies in length (1-4 characters) my current implementation only works from 1000 to 2355. I could poll the lenght of time and make a date format command for each case. My guess is that there's a simpler solution.

   ```
   lines = f_open.readlines()
   # split string and ignore unwanted elements
   for line in lines:
       _, year, julian, time, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9, value10, *_ = line.split(",")
   # format date, convert julian day-of-year to 'day-month'
       date = "%s-%s %s:%s:00" % (int(year), datetime.strptime(julian, "%j").strftime("%m-%d"), time[:2], time[2:])
       with open(targetName, 'a') as target:
           target.write(",".join((date, "1", value1+"\n")))
           target.write(",".join((date, "2", value2+"\n")))
           target.write(",".join((date, "3", value3+"\n")))
           target.write(",".join((date, "4", value4+"\n")))
           target.write(",".join((date, "5", value5+"\n")))
           target.write(",".join((date, "6", value6+"\n")))
           target.write(",".join((date, "7", value7+"\n")))
           target.write(",".join((date, "8", value8+"\n")))
           target.write(",".join((date, "9", value9+"\n")))
           target.write(",".join((date, "10", value10+"\n")))
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in python modules should be sufficient. Avoid [premature optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) and only look for ways to improve speed and efficiency if the simple solutions turn out to be too slow.

```
from datetime import datetime

line = "1,2011,54,0,.375,-.183,2.325,1.221,0,.016,0,0,431.4,.345,1.563,25.13,13.23"

# split string and ignore 4th and every thing from the 6th element on
id, year, julian, _, value, *_ = line.split(",")

# format date, convert julian day-of-year to 'day-month'
date = "%s-%s 00:00:00" % (int(year), datetime.strptime(julian, "%j").strftime("%d-%m"))

print(",".join((date, id, value)))
#>>> 2011-23-02 00:00:00,1,.375

# could cast to numeric types if needed
#id = int(id)
#value = float(value)
```

Leap years in real Julian dates are not handled easily, especially when looking at the Wiki article about the [Julian calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) - it's not even consistent (changed to the calendar system around 45BC for instance).

The `datetime` module does take leap years into accout however, if you provide it the year and the day of year:

```
>>> datetime.strptime("2004 60", "%Y %j")
datetime.datetime(2004, 2, 29, 0, 0)

>>> datetime.strptime("2005 60", "%Y %j")
datetime.datetime(2005, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```

So you can calculate the date like:

```
date = datetime.strptime(year+julian, "%Y%j").strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
```

And all together with the splitting of the values to multiple lines:

```
from datetime import datetime

# ...
lines = f_open.readlines()

# split string and ignore unwanted elements
for line in lines:
    _, year, julian, time, *values = line.split(",")

# format date, convert julian day-of-year to 'day-month'
    date = datetime.strptime(year+julian, "%Y%j").strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
    time = datetime.strptime(time.rjust(4, "0"), "%H%M").strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    timestamp = "%s %s" % (date, time)

    with open(targetName, 'a') as target:
        for i, value in enumerate(values[:10], 1):
            target.write(",".join((timestamp, str(i), value)))
            target.write("\n")
```

Comment: An elegant solution for the time conversation is still needed (see update). Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated answer with a modified version of your script.

Comment: I'm trying to add seconds (which come in fractions often - e.g. .25) I just need the full seconds. Tried `time = datetime.strptime(time.rjust(4, "0")+seconds[:2].rjust(2, "0"), "%H%M%S" ).strftime("%H:%M:%S")` but obviously thats only working if you have two numbers before the seperator.

Comment: Is 0.25 = a quarter of a minute, so 15 seconds? You could try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850607/python-fraction-of-seconds or parse this part manually.

Comment: 0.25 is a quarter of a second and should become 0.

Comment: Just pick the seconds fraction part and round(), ceil() or floor() it. Or use `...%S.%f` to catch the the decimal point and the fraction and ignore it.